# migrate the contents of a mysql table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a small problem I have two mysql tables "data" and "datas" that have the same structure. The problem is that the first data table is already filled and contains data that I want to migrate to the second table "datas" but I have a field that I just added the two tables a field that call "status" and before completing this field I do a check to see if the status is 'pro' or 'share'.
But on the first table "data", and since I just added the status fields, the data stored before, have the status to NULL.
What I want to do is to make a script that takes all the stored data "data" and do a verification for each line, and fill the "status" fields with 'pro' or 'part' and stored all deuxièeme in the table "datas".

I use Mysql.
I need a script to check each line and see if the status is 'pro' or 'part', if you have ideas do not hesitate to tell me.

[picture of data table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjQC.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "do a verification for each line, and fill the "status" fields with 'pro' or 'part"   What determines if the status field is pro or part?  This seems pretty straight forward as a [insert into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) with a case statement to set the status.

Comment: The thing that determines if the status field is 'pro' or 'hand' is in the fields 'content' which is a column of my table and contains a character string format JSON json object as follows:
And I have to retrieve an object "type:" pro "or" type: 'share', "and see if it is 'pro' or 'share' and check each line for the fields 'content' and see if the object type as value. and change the status in relation to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO DATAS(IDDATA, CONTENT, DATE, TOTAL, UPDATEDATE, STATUT)
SELECT 
    IDDATA, 
    CONTENT, 
    DATE, 
    TOTAL, 
    UPDATEDATE, 
    CASE VARIABLE
        WHEN 'CONDITION' THEN 'PRO'
        WHEN 'CONDITION' THEN 'PART'
        ELSE 'DEFAULT_VALUE'
    END AS STATUT
FROM DATA
```

you can use JSON_EXTRACT if available on your mysql version but json content has to be well formatted.

```
JSON_EXTRACT('{"pk": "12", "order": "1234","type":"part"}', '$.type')
```

Full Example

```
INSERT INTO DATAS(IDDATA, CONTENT, DATE, TOTAL, UPDATEDATE, STATUT)
SELECT 
    IDDATA, 
    CONTENT, 
    DATE, 
    TOTAL, 
    UPDATEDATE, 
    CASE JSON_EXTRACT(CONTENT, '$.type')
        WHEN 'pro' THEN 'PRO'
        WHEN 'part' THEN 'PART'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS STATUT
FROM DATA
```

Comment: The thing that determines if the status field is 'pro' or 'part' is in the fields 'content' which is a column of my table and contains a character string format JSON json object as follows: "{'pk':'12','order':{'adr':'blabla',...},type:'part',.......}"
And I must check an object json and see if "type:" pro "or" type: 'part', " and check each line for the fields 'content' and see if the object type as value. and change the status field  in relation to the result.

Comment: Hello ,
I want to thank you first for your efforts, but I wanted to know because I work on MySQL Workbench 6.3 and when I try to execute your code to me it appears as what the function does not exist JSON_EXTRACT?  what can I do?
thank you

Comment: Can you post the error, it is going to be a lot easier to troubleshoot that way

Comment: JSON extract don't work in mysql server 5.5, to resolve this probleme i did a script with php and it works. Thank you

Comment: I am glad you sorted it out.

Comment: Thank's Jevl ^^ I wonder if you know how I can do to prepared a html page from a php page. This work involves preparing a page for the user that it does not expect the php page that loads, it will already prepared page.

Comment: I quite don't understand what is that you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all fields have the same order in both tables and status is the last field.

```
INSERT INTO datas(iddata,content, date, total, updatedate, statut)
    SELECT iddata,content, date, total, updatedate, 
           case when 1=1 then 'Pro' else 'Share' end as statut
    FROM data D
```

Obviously you have to update the case statement to fit the rules to determine pro vs share.

You should be able to use [JSON_Extract()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) to pull out the specific type you're after assuming it's always in the same position within the json document.

So given your json document... something like...  though may need to wrap it in a case statement if you don't want the exact values from.  and you may need to change the field "status" to the correct field name in the table containing the json.

```
INSERT INTO datas(iddata,content, date, total, updatedate, statut)
    SELECT iddata,content, date, total, updatedate, 
           JSON_EXTRACT(status, "$.type") as statut
    FROM data D
```